# Why use set state in react when I can directly push into the array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I've searched for it but haven't found a definite answer to this question.

I have this component with states

```js
function ChatWindow() {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([])
    const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState('')

    function sendMessage(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        messages.push(newMessage)    // This
        setNewMessage('')
    }

    function sendMessage2(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        setMessages([...messages, newMessage])    // Vs this
        setNewMessage('')
    }
}
```

The `sendMessage()` and `sendMessage2()` are called via button of a form.

My question is that both of them work, so why should I even bother with using `setMessages` or there is a good reason for that?

I keep reading that we shouldn't modify state variables directly otherwise page/component won't rerender. But the messages on the front end get added fine both ways.

Help me out, please.

Comment: What part of [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly) is unclear? Just understand it's an anti-pattern to mutate state in React as it can lead to unexpected side-effects and results that can be tricky to diagnose and debug. If it helps, think if it as a React commandment: "Thou shall not mutate state!" The code in your example may only be working since you are updating more than one state and the other state is exposing the mutation since the component rerendered.

Comment: you should not modify state directly. That might work, but will eventually lead to unexpected results, which will take ages to find the root source of the trouble

Comment: Because you have to follow philosophy of framework you are working with and philosophy of react is immutability. That means you are not to mutate a state directly , instead use in build state management API. React internally depends on this concept to perform optimum comparison of two versions of a state to figure out a variable is changes and consequently update the UI for you.